# How can I remove a tuple from my corpus TF-IDF?

Tags: python, tuples, gensim, tf-idf

**I have this code**

from gensim import models
import numpy as np

**Create the TF-IDF model**
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus, smartirs= "ntc)

**Show the TF-IDF weights**
for doc in tfidf[corpus]:
    print([[dictionary[id], np.around(freq, decimals=7)] for id, freq in doc])

**Then, I have this result**

[['brocolli', 0.5491093], ['brother', 0.1237955], ['but', 0.1237955], ['eat', 0.568619], ['good', 0.3660728], ['like', 0.2843095], ['not', 0.1830364], ['rata', 0.1237955], ['saluut', 0.2843095]]
[['brother', 0.1647724], ['rata', 0.1647724], ['around', 0.3784174], ['basebal', 0.3784174], ['drive', 0.1647724], ['lot', 0.3784174], ['mother', 0.2436224], ['practic', 0.3784174], ['spend', 0.3784174], ['time', 0.3784174]]`enter code here`
[['rata', 0.1335974], ['drive', 0.1335974], ['and', 0.3068207], ['blood', 0.3068207], ['caus', 0.3068207], ['expert', 0.3068207], ['health', 0.197529], ['increas', 0.3068207], ['may', 0.3068207], ['pressur', 0.197529], ['some', 0.3068207], ['suggest', 0.3068207],['tension',0.3068207], ['that', 0.197529]]

I want to remove all the tuples < 0.2 
For exaple the word "DRIVE"= 0.1335 I want to remove this tuple. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the original corpus, or only from the output of this loop? What have you tried so far and what were your results, and how was it different from what you want?

Comment: I want to remove from my original corpus, I made  in manual way I mean iterating each tuple but is not working. I wonder if there is a more effective way ro resolve this. Because I can not find a method from gensim that could help me